# Magento1.9 Admin Login

Tags: php, authentication, admin, magento-1.9

I spend the whole day figuring this out, but cannot solve this.
I read a lot of posts about this but none of the solutions worked.
After fresh install of mangeto1.9 I cannot login as admin.

I also modified my Varien.php like this

```
 $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
         //   'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        //    'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        //    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
        /*
        if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
            unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
            if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
                unset($cookieParams['secure']);
                if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                    unset($cookieParams['domain']);
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
            $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
        }
        */
```

In my /var/session folder sessions files are created ( but empty ).

I also tried on few browsers.

What I see is that I got a cookie for .magentoplayground.mine instead of magentoplayground.mine but I dont know how to solve this.

Further my cookie is valid regarding the lifetime.

If anyone could help, this would be great

***EDIT***
Still not solved, from what I read the database seems not be fully installed but I cannot figure out why.
Using Bitnami stack on windows shows me a lot more database entries which are missing in my case

thanks

Comment: Are you on localhost? If yes then try accessing admin through 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: no no I am using Vbox for this

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it seems either you have entered or magento setup has wrongly inserted value for cookie domain i.e. '.magentoplayground.mine' instead of 'magentoplayground.mine'. I would recommend you to run following MySQL query to the database you have been using for your magento store.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'magentoplayground.mine' WHERE `path` LIKE '%web/cookie/cookie_domain%' AND `scope_id` = 0;
```

I hope it will help you out. 
[Note:- Once you have updated the value please remove all cookies and cache data]

Comment: I now have an entry in 

default 0 web/cookie/cookie_domain magentoplayground.mine

but it does not work :(

I deleted everything in var/cache and var/session and cleared browser cookies